# Need to create a regex in which only 0 and 1 can come and 1 can come only 5 times?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to create a regex that can include 11111,011111,101111,101010101 etc but only five time 1 rest zero.Can anyone please reply with suitable regex for the same

Comment: Something like `/0*10*10*10*10*10*/` ( or more compactly /0*1{5}0*/) ? There might be a simpler way though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `1{5}` will only pass continue five `'1'`s

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yeah that was just to illustrate, it's missing `()` around the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is:

```
^(?!(?:.*1){6,})[01]+$
```

`(?!(?:.*1){6,})` is negative lookahead checking that there is no 6 or more than 6 `1s` ahead.

[Try it online](http://regex101.com/r/bP0zO0)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner because dot-star free:

```
^(?!0*(?:10*){5}1)[01]+$
```